grub boot delay 10s. GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0 hack
I want to avoid any delay because of grub in my UEFI PC with Ubuntu 24. I have the only one OS and I am absolutely not interesting in any other/recover options. By default timeout is 30s but I already reduced it to 10s. But I want 0, not default 10s comes from 30_os-prober
So I try to use GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0 hack. But after sudo update-grub again default 10s... Why hack doesn't work?
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="spectre_v2=off nopti"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0

P.S. I don't want every time change 10 sec from code from /boot/grub/grub.cfg, such solution works but not good...
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi


I found solution in comments to post:
sudo apt purge os-prober
sudo update-grub

